# Json Objects to Valid Json Array Conversion

Tags: java, arrays, json

I've series of Json Objects that look like below

> {      "Title":"The Avengers",    "Year":"2012",    "Genre":"Action,
>   Sci-Fi, Thriller",    "Director":"Joss Whedon",    "imdbRating":"8.1",
>   } {      "Title":"Batman Begins",    "Year":"2005",
>   "Genre":"Action, Adventure",    "Director":"Christopher Nolan",
>   "imdbRating":"8.3", } {      "Title":"The Dark Knight",
>   "Year":"2008",    "Genre":"Action, Crime, Drama",
>   "Director":"Christopher Nolan",    "imdbRating":"9.0", }

Can any one help to convert the above in to valid Json Array using **JAVA** like below?

[
   {
      "Title":"The Avengers",
      "Year":"2012",
      "Genre":"Action, Sci-Fi, Thriller",
      "Director":"Joss Whedon",
      "imdbRating":"8.1"
   },
   {
      "Title":"Batman Begins",
      "Year":"2005",
      "Genre":"Action, Adventure",
      "Director":"Christopher Nolan",
      "imdbRating":"8.3"
   },
   {
      "Title":"The Dark Knight",
      "Year":"2008",
      "Genre":"Action, Crime, Drama",
      "Director":"Christopher Nolan",
      "imdbRating":"9.0"
   }
]

Comment: You might want to look at Apache Wink or javax.json

Comment: Please this your ugly json formating. It hurt my eyes.

Comment: Where did you get this data? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

your question its self has the answer. Make sure that your json is wrapped with array brackets "[]" then you can convert the same at the java end using some json library like Gson (https://github.com/google/gson)